# & sign in url rewriting

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting

hi how can i get full url with & sign

```
RewriteRule category/(.*)$ categories.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

my url is category/pets-&-wets/ but when i get

> echo $_GET['url']; it shows only pets-

any suggestions thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's happening because the `&` marks the start of another `GET` argument - since the rewritten URL would end up looking like `categories.php?url=pets-&-wet`.

You need to encode your `&` as `%26`, so your URL is `category/pets-%26-wet`.

Better still, whatever is generating your slugs replaces ampersands by `and`, so your URL would be `category/pets-and-wet`.